# How to correctly check any_cast available?

Tags: c++, stdoptional, stdany

I have some input which can be simple value or container, packed in `std::any`. I don't want to use exceptions, so I call `noexcept` variadic `any_cast` method which return pointer or `nullptr` to value of any.

I can verify any cast available with `typeid()` but I don't want to use it and want to find some alternative. Some typetraits methods, such as `decltype`, `declval` or so on. Or simply using `std::optional`.

But optional seems is still damp and unstable in this case. MSVC compiler the program breaks at runtime in the depths of the `std::optional` source code.

```
#include <optional>
#include <any>
#include <utility>

int main() {

int input = 1; 

std::initializer_list<int> input2;
input2 = {1,2,3}; 

std::any any1 = input;
std::any any2 = input2;

std::optional o1 = *std::any_cast<int>(&any1);
std::optional p2 = *std::any_cast<int>(&any2);

// **std::forward<int & __ptr64>**(...) in  _Optional_destruct_base return nullptr.

}
```

Actually, typetraits check will be the best way to test `any_cast` possibility. But I still confused with c++ metaprogramming.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the returned pointer to see if it is null?

Comment: *"I can verify any cast available with `typeid()` but"*. If your range of possible types is limited, `std::variant` might be more appropriated.

Comment: Dereferencing `nullptr` (as for `p2`) is UB.

Comment: I had to, but I didn’t want to create an extra link, and I thought that the std::optional would check what it receives, because in case of a successful cast, it will store the object and I can use it by renaming the optional itself. I am wary of working with raw pointers myself.

Comment: That's not how optional works.  You need to manually do that check before you dereference the pointer

Comment: " If your range of possible types is limited" I do, right after bad cast I cast any to variant then. But this is second step, when I have already know that it is not some simple number type.

Comment: `any_cast` is a run-time feature, you can't use it statically (via "type traits"). You should probably explain why you have `std::any` in the first place. There could be a better solution.

Comment: Any cast itself use type traits check before casting. I just do not understand what it exactly checks, that is why I could not repeat it. But any cast as sure knows how to do that.

Comment: You should probably explain why you have std::any in the first place... I practicing with functional programming and this method is part of proccessor which iterates some complex lambda term list, every term can return value, list of values or function to higher order function so  each node decompresses the previous node's std::any response.

Answer (score 1):

Never dereference a pointer without knowing it is non null.

This in general applies to all nullable types; in C++ these are generally types that support unary `*` and `->`.

```
std::optional o1 = std::any_cast<int>(&any1)?*std::any_cast<int>(&any1):std::optional<int>();
```

for example.

**any** dereference of a null nullable type is UB, which can work, crash, or do absolutely anything else as far as the C++ standard is concerned.

But also consider std variant if your set of stored types is closed (does not change).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `std::optional` and don't want to use pointers, I think you could write your own function that performs the pointer check for you and return the proper `std::optional`, something like:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> get_v_opt(const std::any & a)
{
    if(const T * v = std::any_cast<T>(&a))
        return std::optional<T>(*v);
    else
        return std::nullopt;
}
```

Here in a usage example of how to use such a function:

```
int main()
{
    std::any a(42);

    std::optional opt_int = get_v_opt<int>(a);
    std::optional opt_str = get_v_opt<std::string>(a);

    if(opt_int.has_value())
        std::cout << "a is an int with value: " << opt_int.value() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "a is not an int\n";

    if(opt_str.has_value())
        std::cout << "a is a string with value: " << opt_str.value() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "a is not a string\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output (for this example):

> a is an int with value: 42
> a is not a string

Comment: Thank you. Optional is tempopary object and not class member in this case. I just plaing around with it, but as far as I understand any_cast also check 'any' before casting with some type traits. Such as : is_constructible_v<remove_cv_t<_Ty>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty>. I want to use something same, but do not exactly understand what is it checks. Simple decltype(T), decltype(input,type()) not working because even if first and second are ints, one was declared in compile time and another in runtime.

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev This is not true actually, `std::any_cast` doesn't check that type trait. If you look at [a good reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast), it is mentioned that this type trait is a requirement for using `std::any_cast`, otherwise the program is ill-formed. But since we use the pointer version, this doesn't concern us :)

Comment: @SergeyInozemcev With a `std::optional` as a class member, this works basically the same. I have written an example for you [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9d393f3f6).

Comment: thank you! I mean std::optional is rather heavy object for using it with not class member usage, you example is valuable in itself though